# Python, override initial import dynamically using importlib not working

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I have a python file script_00.py, where I import some module at the beginning:

```
from some_path import Core
```

However, based on the value of a variable, I might have to override this and load an alternative version of this module. This is the folder structure:

```
core_alternative_version_folder/
|____ core_custom.py -> Core

src/
|____ script_00.py
```

so, I want to import the implementation of core_custom as Core.
I tried using (always in script_00.py):

```
if condition is True:
    Core = importlib.import_module("Core", package="..core_alternative_version_folder.core_custom.py")
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Core'
```